# Can we Use masterPage in silverlight4 application

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is it Possible to use masterpage with silverlight4 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Silverlight navigation template project available in VS2010 gives you the equivalent of a master page in the form of MainPage.xaml.

Answer (score 1):

There is no master page concept in silverlight. try using usercontrols and implement the master page. Iframe and silverlight controls should do the trick. 
Anyways let us wait and hear from an expert if there is a better work around.